# C# - How to get Class Name and Line Number when an Exception is called

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need two methods, one for getting the Class from where the exception was called, and another one which gets the line number where an exception was called.

So far I have this code, which gets me the Class Name and Line Number together (example: DatabaseHandler.cs:line 70):

```
    private string GetClassAndLine()
    {
        string tempName = e.GetBaseException().ToString();
        int tempPosition = 0;
        int length = tempName.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (tempName.ElementAt(i).Equals('\\'))
            {
                tempPosition = i + 1;
            }
        }
        return tempName.Substring(tempPosition, length - tempPosition);
    }
```

So if you have any ideas how I could get them individually, it would be of great help. These are then passed into Oracle to store any exceptions which occur.

Update 2:

I am currently testing this code, as some suggested:

```
        private string GetClassName()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true); 
        return trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName;
    }

    private int GetLineNumber()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true); 
        return trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
    }
```

This is what was returned at a particular Database Exception. No Line Number or Class Name where it was triggered. How can I get that?

```
    Error was found at Class: Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.     
    Line Number: 0
```

What I want is for Example: "Class: Logging.cs, Line: 57"

Thanks, 
Ryan

Comment: It works for me, but after making some adaptations (I am using Compact Framework 3.9):
- Frame.GetFileLineNumber runs but always cause an exception. I removed it.
- The level of the Frame considered is dependent of your call stack. In my case I have to consider GetFrame(1) because I have to bypass the call to my log() function

Answer (score 23):

You can do like this

```
try
{
    // Some code that can cause an exception.

    throw new Exception("An error has happened");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, true);

    Console.WriteLine(trace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName);
    Console.WriteLine("Line: " + trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber());
    Console.WriteLine("Column: " + trace.GetFrame(0).GetFileColumnNumber());
}
```

Comment: I thought, You have no source files of  **Oracle.DataAccess.Client** Or that is **RELEASE** version with **/OPTIMIZE** Option. So, you cannot get any further information from that.

Comment: Do you know? that's an example.

Answer (score 4):

`System.Environment.StackTrace`. Useful any time, not just on exceptions. Might need a bit of string manipulation using that though;

If you prefer something a little more hi-tech, you can use `System.Diagnostics.StackFrame`; Check the object browser for full details, but it's got methods for finding the filename, line and column number, etc.

Comment: I am still not sure how to get the class using the Environment.StackTrace, could you please provide an example for getting the class

Comment: Do you mean the specific instance? If so, I think that's impossible. Believe me, I've tried. If you mean the type, then you can use the `GetMethod().DeclaringType` method on the `StackFrame`.

Comment: @Flnn1179 - it's ok, thanks to the 2nd post I know what you wanted to say, check my Update 2, above. I am currently testing that because I got some errors in other parts of my code.

Comment: @Flnn1179 - It did not work exactly as I expected, is there any better way? See my update for output + code

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following `class DebugE` to trace exceptions and log stuff in the application:
 It outputs the  Thread# DateTime, **ClassName.MethodName, Line & Col numbers** and the exception message.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace YourApp
{
class DebugE
{
    public static void d(Exception e)
    {
        try
        {
            MethodBase site = e.TargetSite;//Get the methodname from the exception.
            string methodName = site == null ? "" : site.Name;//avoid null ref if it's null.
            methodName = ExtractBracketed(methodName);

            StackTrace stkTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                //In most cases GetFrame(0) will contain valid information, but not always. That's why a small loop is needed. 
                var frame = stkTrace.GetFrame(i);
                int lineNum = frame.GetFileLineNumber();//get the line and column numbers
                int colNum = frame.GetFileColumnNumber();
                string className = ExtractBracketed(frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.FullName);
                Trace.WriteLine(ThreadAndDateInfo + "Exception: " + className + "." + methodName + ", Ln " + lineNum + " Col " + colNum + ": " + e.Message);
                if (lineNum + colNum > 0)
                    break; //exit the for loop if you have valid info. If not, try going up one frame...
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            //Avoid any situation that the Trace is what crashes you application. While trace can log to a file. Console normally not output to the same place.
            Console.WriteLine("Tracing exception in d(Exception e)" + ee.Message);
        }
    }
    public static void d(string str)
    {
        try
        {
            StackFrame frame = new StackFrame(1);
            var method = frame.GetMethod();
            string name = ExtractBracketed(method.Name);//extract the content that is inside <brackets> the rest is irrelevant 

            Trace.WriteLine(ThreadAndDateInfo + method.DeclaringType + "." + name + ": " + str);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Tracing exception in d(string str)" + e.Message);
        }
    }

    private static string ExtractBracketed(string str)
    {
        string s;
        if (str.IndexOf('<') > -1) //using the Regex when the string does not contain <brackets> returns an empty string.
            s = Regex.Match(str, @"\<([^>]*)\>").Groups[1].Value;
        else
            s = str; 
        if (s == "")
            return  "'Emtpy'"; //for log visibility we want to know if something it's empty.
        else
            return s;

    }

    public static string ThreadAndDateInfo
    {
        //returns thread number and precise date and time.
        get { return "[" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM HH:mm:ss.ffffff") + "] "; }
    }
}
}
```

Call if from anywhere in your application:

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
    DebugE.d(e);
}
```

To use it for plain logging, call `DebugE.d("some text");` 
It will return the same but without the line and col numbers.

Note that **for production applications** I always end up **calling a "simpler" call systematically:
 `void debug(string methodName, exception e)`**. 
 This is because **the "nicer" solution above DID NOT ALWAYS RETURN THE CORRECT METHOD information** to me. If my guess is correct, this would be the case if your exception occurs in a method that does not have a `try catch`, but was called by another method that does have a 'try catch'. If this is the only reason, you can say "i'll add proper try catch". The problem is that in real life you get a real problem, a real log to analyse. When you notice the irrelevant or insufficient method information you don't get the chance to go back to your code, add the try/catch and quickly reproduce the exception. You just **end up with missing information to deal with...**
The current improved methods digs a few frames deep to try and get around this and retrieve the class, line and column in these special situations it could look like this **(the trace on the 3rd frame actually returns a valid name and line number)**:
`[1 - 21/11 14:37:50.424914] Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay, Ln 0 Col 0: The value needs to translate in milliseconds to -1 (signifying an infinite timeout), 0 or a positive integer less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.
Parameter name: delay
[1 - 21/11 14:37:50.425914] Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay, Ln 0 Col 0: The value needs to translate in milliseconds to -1 (signifying an infinite timeout), 0 or a positive integer less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.
Parameter name: delay
[1 - 21/11 14:37:50.426415] Exception: ScheduleAction.Delay, Ln 156 Col 17: The value needs to translate in milliseconds to -1 (signifying an infinite timeout), 0 or a positive integer less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue.
Parameter name: delay`

Comment: To make the Trace print to a file, add this to your configuation:`<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="textListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="trace.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>`

Comment: could you be seeing the wrong method information, because you are using ReflectedType instead of DeclaringType?

Comment: Possible. I haven't used it in quite a while (not debugging stuff that justifies these recently)